# Pikurossword, or: Three-in-One

Tags: grid-deduction, crosswords

<sub>This is an entry into the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #36](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/fortnightly-topic-challenge-36-twisted-classics-1). [edit: i hope this wasn't too bad for my first puzzle here! let me know how i did :)]</sub>

The answer to this puzzle should answer the question: *what is required to solve this puzzle?*

[image: Pikurossword]

**Across**
1. Many hands make this? (7, 2 wds.)
3. Promotion (2, abbr.)
5. Transformation's namesake (4)
7. Expression of disgust (4)
8. Frequently (3)
10. Nickname for mother (2)
11. European currency (4)
13. Resembling a lion or a certain pope (4)
15. Brand name of Furosemide (3)
17. Injury caused by repetitive mechanical exertions (3, init.)
18. Canvas (2)
19. Takes revenge (4, 2 wds.)

**Down**
1. To produce an egg (3)
2. Sharp increase in price (4)
4. Comprising two parts (4)
5. Forked or branching (4)
6. Abnormal narrowing of a passage in the body (6)
9. Transport goods in bulk (3)
10. Of metal, in liquid form (4)
12. Reactive (4)
14. Spanish form of "bravo" (3)
16. Name of sign found in email addresses (2)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was working this independently of QuantumTwinkie, but I think the crossword portion is solved:

> The twist is that certain entries need to have a few letters filled into a single square, like LIGH(TWO)RK and (FOUR)IER. These happen to form numbers.
>  [image]

The other bit/two bits of this puzzle is that

> The numbers in the grid form givens for a [Kuromasu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuromasu) puzzle. The clues on the right are clues to the number of shaded cells in that row, a-la [Picross/Nonograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram). These clues can be used together to find all the shaded cells in the grid. The puzzle itself isn't too hard, but if anyone wants a walkthough, let me know.

The final grid looks like this:

> [image]
>  The shaded spaces show us what we needed to solve this puzzle, **GREY CELLS**.

Thanks for the puzzle!